# Write python table to SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have [pytrends](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/) output like this:

```
>>> from pytrends.request import TrendReq
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pyodbc as db
<...>
>>> pytrend.interest_over_time()
date        Cat    Dog    Bat    Rat    Roo    IsPartial
2017-05-28   61      1     27     23     24    False
2017-06-04   61      1     25     28     27    False
2017-06-11   64      2     23     22     22    False
2017-06-18   75      3     27     27     26    False
```

How can I insert this data into an identical MS SQL table as follows?

```
CREATE TABLE GoogleTrends (
 [Date] DATE
,[Cat] TINYINT
,[Dog] TINYINT
,[Bat] TINYINT
,[Rat] TINYINT
,[Roo] TINYINT
,[IsPartial] BIT
)
```

Steps taken:

```
>>> con = db.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;DATABASE=DBName')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
```

Then should go something like

```
qry = '''INSERT INTO dbo.GoogleTrends
        (Date, Cat, Dog, Bat, Rat, Roo, IsPartial)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        '''
```

But I am not quite sure. Anyway, using

```
>>>cur.execute(qry, param_values)
```

results in error: **'The SQL contains 6 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'** if I assign

```
param_values = pytrend.interest_over_time()
```

Comment: The error message says it all ... try supplying 6 parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, but how can I get separate values from this data set?

Comment: You need to loop over each row and insert to the database. `param_values` is only 1 parameter, as the error says

Comment: Or, you can look over the pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: `pytrend.interest_over_time().to_sql(conn, 'GoogleTrends')` something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `to_sql` for SQL Server requires an SQLAlchemy connection and not raw connection, consider the cursor method iterating through rows of the dataframe using same prepared SQL statement:

```
for idx, row in pytrend.interest_over_time().iterrows():
  cur.execute(qry, row)
  con.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, but it does not work either - the same error.

Comment: Interesting! I am thinking now `pytrend.interest_over_time()` is not a dataframe. Check its type: `type(pytrend.interest_over_time())`.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to use SQLAlchemy, though it is an option.
if you want to use pyodbc you almost have done that.

```
qry = '''INSERT INTO dbo.GoogleTrends
        (Date, Cat, Dog, Bat, Rat, Roo, IsPartial)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        '''
cur.execute(qry ,(Date_val, Cat_val, Dog_val, Bat_val, Rat_val, Roo_val, IsPartial_val))
```

note that the second argument in execute function accept a tuple too.
However consider two additional notes:
1) you need to create your table in sql server yourself; pyodbc  wont create the table for you
2) after inserting the data you need an additional line of code:

```
con.commit()
```